# How to fix this DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame2

> DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float). Implicit conversion to integers using `int` is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.

`win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))`

> DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float). Implicit conversion to integers using `int` is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.

`win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is related to the coordinate parameter of [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Floating point coordinates, would mean that the origin of the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is somewhere in between to pixels in the window. That doesn't make much sense. The coordinates are automatically, implicitly truncated and that is indicated by the warning.
Use either [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to convert the floating point coordinates to integral numbers:

```py
win.blit(playerStand, (round(x), round(y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The message appears also with explicit conversions so, to be safe do:

```
a = round(x)
b = round(y)
win.blit(playerStand, (a, b))
```

W1JGH